# How to get a tables TD-offset()'s with jQuery 1.5.2 (Drupal7)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal-7, offset

I need to find the correct .offset()-position of a tabled TD-elements within a Drupal7-generated HTML-site (jQuery_update installed). I use

```
        $('#contenttable td').each(function(){ 
            console.log($(this).offsetParent());
            console.log($(this).offset().left);
        });
```

within my

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //$(document).ready(function(){
```

of my script.js to get the offset().left-position but the console allways traces me '0' for all TDs.

When I use the Safari Developer Console the output of

```
jQuery('#contenttable td:nth-child(2)').offset().left
```

is '1728', so it seems to work at all. But why doesn't it work from within my DOCUMENT.READY?

The .offsetParent() is BODY by the way... And changing some of the parents DIV's position to absolute or relative didn't give any change, too.
THNX!

edit: seems not to work for any element at all.

Comment: You know that `jQuery(function($) {` and `$(document).ready(function(){` do the same thing, right? So nesting them like that is unnecessary. Just wanted to point it out

Comment: And why do you keep mixing the use of `jQuery()` and `$()`? Just stick with one. Using `$` is fine, unless you're using another library that uses that identifier...like Prototype. Are you using any other libraries like that?

Comment: Yes I do. In Drupal you need to nest jQuery like that.

Comment: What do you mean? Anyways, try using `console.log(jQuery(this).offsetParent());` - notice how I changed it to `jQuery` and not `$`

Comment: @Ian: But this seems to be not the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I nest it to use jquery like I know it. I like using the $.

Comment: But why are you _also_ using `jQuery`? You don't need to use both, especially for binding `$(document).ready`. `jQuery(function($) {` IS the same thing. You basically have `jQuery(function($) { jQuery(function($) { // Your code }); });`. So are you saying that you use a library like Prototype?

Comment: @Ian: Using console.log(jQuery(this).offset()); doesn't change anything. offsetParent still is BODY and offset().left still 0.

Comment: I tested to uncomment the line '$(document).ready(function(){'. This doesn't change anything.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say that commenting/removing that line will change anything. I was just saying that it's unnecessary

Comment: @Ian: O.k. Thank you. I am not that deep into JavaScript. Let's please focus on the problem again.

Comment: Is the element hidden at first? `.offset()` doesn't work on hidden elements. See what this says too: `console.log($(this).is(":visible"));`

Comment: hey, thats a good point I didn't know. it is hidden, yes!

Comment: works - thank you, man! please add as an answer so I could mark as solved.

Comment: but how could I hide the content AND calculate all the stuff in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `jQuery.offset` does not work on hidden elements, because the browser doesn't bother rendering them at all. So if possible, you need to make the element visible in order to get its `offset`. According to [jquery: get the offset of hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974323/jquery-get-the-offset-of-hidden-element) , you should be able to call `.show()` on the table/content, get the desired `offset`, then call `.hide()` on it. This show/hide should not be apparent to the user, as it won't repaint the page since it's in the same execution event.