# JQuery measuring position of a hidden element

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get `$element.position()` working for a hidden (i.e. `display:hidden`) element?

Comment: jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

Comment: Makes sense, I just wanted a 'risk on me' type of solution.

Comment: If you know where the element is in your Dom tree, you could get position of its previous sibling or parent as required and then add the height/width of the said element to get your current position. However this may not be very easy in a fuildic layout.

Comment: Just for the records: `display: hidden` is no valid css, either `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
mypos = $('#myelement').css({
  visibility: 'hidden',
  display: 'block'
}).position();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try :

```
var pos = $element.show().position();
$element.hide();
```

Only in exceptional circumstances (some untimely interrupt by some process outside the current window/tab), will the element be momentarily rendered.

Answer (score 1):

'display:none;' removes the element from the document so it does not have a position. You could try a quick 'display: block; visibility: hidden;', get the position, and hide it again.

Edit:
This is explained on this question's page already: [jquery: get the offset of hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974323/jquery-get-the-offset-of-hidden-element)

Comment: I can still see the element as part of the visual tree, showing and hiding causes a flicker. I know why it's disable but in my case it's absolute safe to measure the top and height for a hidden element

Comment: i know, it doesn't "remove" it from the document, but it does, as you noticed, remove it from the renderable elements. here is a better explanation and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974323/jquery-get-the-offset-of-hidden-element