# Handle cells with rowspan when hiding table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have a [table containing cells with rowspan attributes](http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/yaFvc), I would like to:

1. Whenever a `tr` is hidden, the table will rearrange itself correctly
2. Whenever a `tr` is shown again, it will be restored to original state

So if you have a [table like this](http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/yaFvc) clicking on `X` shouldn't destroy the layout.
and click a `come back` button, should restore the original layout.

(try removing all rows from bottom-up, and than restoring them from right-to-left, this is a desired flow)

I had some semi-solutions, but all seem too complicated, and i'm sure there is a nice way to handle this.

Comment: Some - admittedly sketchy - ideas: you'll have to decrement `rowspan`s and increment `colspan`s after a row is hidden. original values of the attributes can be stored in `data-` attributes. Updates will be Necessary even on hidden rows to allow for Independent sequences in which Rows are concealed and Restored. The Bookkeeping may be shifted to localstorage.

Comment: is it not restoring now? on clicking x what actually happening is it just hiding

Comment: @zod now nothing special is happening. what should happen is: click X on red row, all the rowspanned tds should move down to white row. and when clicking "come back" on red button, the change should be restored to initial state.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK I really spent a hell of a long time over this question, so here goes...

**For those of you who just want to see the working solution, [click here](http://codepen.io/evenicoulddoit/pen/hHfdz)**

**Update:** I've changed the visual columns calculation method to iterate over the table and create a 2-dimensional array, to see the old method which used the jQuery `offset()` method, [click here](http://codepen.io/evenicoulddoit/pen/GEsIj). The code is shorter, but more time costly.

The problem exists because when we hide a row, whilst we want all the cells to be hidden, we want the *pseudo-cells* — that is, the cells that appear to be in the following rows due to the cells `rowspan` attribute — to persist. To get around this, whenever we come across a hidden cell with a `rowspan`, we try to move it down the the next visible row (decrementing it's `rowspan` value as we go). With either our original cell or it's clone, we then iterate down the table once more for every row that would contain a pseudo-cell, and if the row is hidden we decrement the `rowspan` again. (To understand why, look at the working example, and note that when the blue row is hidden, red cell 9's rowspan must be reduced from 2 to 1, else it would push green 9 right).

With that in mind, we must apply the following function whenever rows are shown/hidden:

```
function calculate_rowspans() {
  // Remove all temporary cells
  $(".tmp").remove();

  // We don't care about the last row
  // If it's hidden, it's cells can't go anywhere else
  $("tr").not(":last").each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);

    // Iterate over all non-tmp cells with a rowspan    
    $("td[rowspan]:not(.tmp)", $tr).each(function() {
      $td = $(this);
      var $rows_down = $tr;
      var new_rowspan = 1;

      // If the cell is visible then we don't need to create a copy
      if($td.is(":visible")) {
        // Traverse down the table given the rowspan
        for(var i = 0; i < $td.data("rowspan") - 1; i ++) {

          $rows_down = $rows_down.next();
          // If our cell's row is visible then it can have a rowspan
          if($rows_down.is(":visible")) {
            new_rowspan ++;
          }
        }
        // Set our rowspan value
        $td.attr("rowspan", new_rowspan);   
      }
      else {
        // We'll normally create a copy, unless all of the rows
        // that the cell would cover are hidden
        var $copy = false;
        // Iterate down over all rows the cell would normally cover
        for(var i = 0; i < $td.data("rowspan") - 1; i ++) {
          $rows_down = $rows_down.next();
          // We only consider visible rows
          if($rows_down.is(":visible")) {
            // If first visible row, create a copy

            if(!$copy) {
              $copy = $td.clone(true).addClass("tmp");
              // You could do this 1000 better ways, using classes e.g
              $copy.css({
                "background-color": $td.parent().css("background-color")
              });
              // Insert the copy where the original would normally be
              // by positioning it relative to it's columns data value 
              var $before = $("td", $rows_down).filter(function() {
                return $(this).data("column") > $copy.data("column");
              });
              if($before.length) $before.eq(0).before($copy);
              else $(".delete-cell", $rows_down).before($copy);
            }
            // For all other visible rows, increment the rowspan
            else new_rowspan ++;
          }
        }
        // If we made a copy then set the rowspan value
        if(copy) copy.attr("rowspan", new_rowspan);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The next, *really* difficult part of the question is calculating at which index to place  the copies of the cells within the row. Note in the example, blue cell 2 has an *actual* index within its row of 0, i.e. it's the first actual cell within the row, however we can see that visually it lies in column 2 (0-indexed).

I took the approach of calculating this only once, as soon as the document is loaded. I then store this value as a data attribute of the cell, so that I can position a copy of it in the right place (I've had many Eureka moments on this one, and made many pages of notes!). To do this calculation, I ended up constructing a 2-dimensional Array `matrix` which keeps track of all of the used-visual columns. At the same time, I store the cells original `rowspan` value, as this will change with hiding/showing rows:

```
function get_cell_data() {
    var matrix = [];  
    $("tr").each(function(i) {
        var $cells_in_row = $("td", this);
        // If doesn't exist, create array for row
        if(!matrix[i]) matrix[i] = [];
        $cells_in_row.each(function(j) {
            // CALCULATE VISUAL COLUMN
            // Store progress in matrix
            var column = next_column(matrix[i]);
            // Store it in data to use later
            $(this).data("column", column);
            // Consume this space
            matrix[i][column] = "x";
            // If the cell has a rowspan, consume space across
            // Other rows by iterating down
            if($(this).attr("rowspan")) {
                // Store rowspan in data, so it's not lost
                var rowspan = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
                $(this).data("rowspan", rowspan);
                for(var x = 1; x < rowspan; x++) {
                    // If this row doesn't yet exist, create it
                    if(!matrix[i+x]) matrix[i+x] = [];
                    matrix[i+x][column] = "x";
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // Calculate the next empty column in our array
    // Note that our array will be sparse at times, and
    // so we need to fill the first empty index or push to end
    function next_column(ar) {
        for(var next = 0; next < ar.length; next ++) {
            if(!ar[next]) return next;
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

Then simply apply this on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_cell_data();
});
```

(Note: whilst the code here is longer than my jQuery `.offset()` alternative, it's probably quicker to calculate. Please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the try, but i'm afraid you missed some requirement: when deleting a row, the cells should be lowered down in the same order (think that if you delete red row, than the rowspanned cells "stays" red all way down).

Comment: So you mean hide the row but if the row has a cell with a rowspan value, that should continue to exist? It's not that hard to do if you explain by what you mean as "stays red" - do you mean the cell inherits the properties of it's original row, or the content remains the same?

Comment: Ah I see, I'll have a play and see what I can come up with!

Comment: Have a look now :) - hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: looks good, let me write some tests for this to make sure it works as expected

Comment: look at this (http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/jvFIo) try removing: purple, dark green, yellow and than return purple

Comment: Ah, nice testing - maybe have an error when a row has no / 1 cell in it. I'll take a look later.

Comment: If anyone wants to help me debug this, I've written some logs which should help [in this pen](http://codepen.io/evenicoulddoit/pen/hAyHb)

Comment: **Updated** Please let me know what you think! :)

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will look at all the solutions here as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks Ian i chose your solution. Anyhow i wasn't very happy with the implementation, so i re-factored your code a bit to be more maintainable and readable (i made a class to handle this table). code is here http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/oAfny  Thanks for help!

Comment: @YardenST great work - you're right, the code I used was very much a "it works" solution, I'll take a look at your class and edit my answer to match if it looks good (which just looking now, I think it does :))

Comment: Yet another important change: you assume in your code that a visible td or tr is ":visible", in HTML in general its not always true, a better approach is to pass a "visible selector" to the function. (in my implementation is [data-visible=true] (think that the table itself could be hidden, than your code will not work..)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what do you mean "you assume in your code that a visible td or tr is ':visible'". Using jQuery visible works upwards - if a parent is hidden then the child is not deemed "visible", [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QwXC/)

Comment: Yes I know that, this is exactly the problem: if the <table> is not visible, and you remove\show rows (using some other code, not the X button) than because all the rows are hidden, the code does not work.

Comment: Why would you show or hide rows in a hidden table? Also, if you were doing that you should just "recalculate" when you show the table again OR just instead of hiding the rows add a class `.hidden` e.g. Either way, I don't see the great importance to the question!

Comment: This is just the case in my website, some other entity is responsible for the table, and it doesn't care/know if its hidden or not. Never mind not that important indeed

Comment: Works correctly, but the speed is slow when dealing with an average number of row (about 400 in my test case)

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-AlainVigeant - I must confess I didn't spend a lot of time cleaning and optimising the code, I just spent an age on the logic. I might clean up if I get the time

Comment: I ended up using a different technique. I don't rowspan, but when hiding/displaying rows, show/hide the content of normaly merged cell if their "owner parent" is visible.

Answer (score 1):

### Working solution - http://codepen.io/jmarroyave/pen/eLkst

This is basically the same solution that i presented before, i just changed how to get the column index to remove the restriction of the jquery.position, and did some refactor to the code.

```
function layoutInitialize(tableId){
  var layout = String();
  var maxCols, maxRows, pos, i, rowspan, idx, xy;

  maxCols = $(tableId + ' tr').first().children().length;
  maxRows = $(tableId + ' tr').length;

  // Initialize the layout matrix
  for(i = 0; i < (maxCols * maxRows); i++){
    layout += '?';
  }

  // Initialize cell data
  $(tableId + ' td').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('color_class'));
    rowspan = 1;
    if($(this).attr('rowspan')){
      rowspan = $(this).attr("rowspan");  
      $(this).data("rowspan", rowspan);  
    }

    // Look for the next position available
    idx = layout.indexOf('?');
    pos = {x:idx % maxCols, y:Math.floor(idx / maxCols)}; 
    // store the column index in the cell for future reposition
    $(this).data('column', pos.x);
    for(i = 0; i < rowspan; i++){
      // Mark this position as not available
      xy = (maxCols * pos.y) + pos.x
      layout = layout.substr(0, xy + (i * maxCols)) + 'X' + layout.substr(xy + (i * maxCols)  + 1);
    }
  });   

}
```

---

### Solution: with jquery.position() - http://codepen.io/jmarroyave/pen/rftdy

This is an alternative solution, it assumes that the first row contains all the information about the number of the table columns and the position of each on.

This aproach *has the restriction that the inizialitation code must be call when the table is visible*, because it depends on the visible position of the columns.

If this is not an issue, hope it works for you

**Initialization**

```
  // Initialize cell data
  $('td').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('color_class'));
    $(this).data('posx', $(this).position().left);
    if($(this).attr('rowspan')){
      $(this).data("rowspan", $(this).attr("rowspan"));  
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE**
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974323/jquery-get-the-offset-of-hidden-element) ensuring the visibility of the table can be manage with

```
  $('table').show();
  // Initialize cell data
  $('td').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('color_class'));
    $(this).data('posx', $(this).position().left);
    if($(this).attr('rowspan')){
      $(this).data("rowspan", $(this).attr("rowspan"));  
    }
  });
  $('table').hide();
```

As Ian said, the main issue to solve in this problem is to calculate the position of the cells when merging the hidden with the visible rows.

I tried to figure it out how the browser implements that funcionality and how to work with that. Then looking the DOM i searched for something like columnVisiblePosition and i found the position attributes and took that way

```
 function getColumnVisiblePostion($firstRow, $cell){
  var tdsFirstRow = $firstRow.children();
  for(var i = 0; i < tdsFirstRow.length; i++){
    if($(tdsFirstRow[i]).data('posx') == $cell.data('posx')){
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

The js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  add_delete_buttons();

  $(window).on("tr_gone", function (e, tr) {
    add_come_back_button(tr);
  });

  // Initialize cell data
  $('td').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('color_class'));
    $(this).data('posx', $(this).position().left);
    if($(this).attr('rowspan')){
      $(this).data("rowspan", $(this).attr("rowspan"));  
    }
  });
});

function calculate_max_rowspans() {
  // Remove all temporary cells
  $(".tmp").remove();

  // Get all rows
  var trs = $('tr'), tds, tdsTarget,
      $tr, $trTarget, $td, $trFirst,
      cellPos, cellTargetPos, i;

  // Get the first row, this is the layout reference
  $trFirst = $('tr').first();

  // Iterate through all rows
  for(var rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < trs.length; rowIdx++){
    $tr = $(trs[rowIdx]);
    $trTarget = $(trs[rowIdx+1]);
    tds = $tr.children();

    // For each cell in row
    for(cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < tds.length; cellIdx++){
      $td = $(tds[cellIdx]);
      // Find which one has a rowspan
      if($td.data('rowspan')){
        var rowspan = Number($td.data('rowspan'));

        // Evaluate how the rowspan should be display in the current state
        // verify if the cell with rowspan has some hidden rows
        for(i = rowIdx; i < (rowIdx + Number($td.data('rowspan'))); i++){
          if(!$(trs[i]).is(':visible')){
            rowspan--;
          }
        }

        $td.attr('rowspan', rowspan);

        // if the cell doesn't have rows hidden within, evaluate the next cell
        if(rowspan == $td.data('rowspan')) continue;

        // If this row is hidden copy the values to the next row
        if(!$tr.is(':visible') && rowspan > 0) {
          $clone = $td.clone();
          // right now, the script doesn't care about copying data, 
          // but here is the place to implement it
          $clone.data('rowspan', $td.data('rowspan') - 1);
          $clone.data('posx', $td.data('posx'));
          $clone.attr('rowspan',  rowspan);
          $clone.addClass('tmp');

          // Insert the temp node in the correct position
          // Get the current cell position
          cellPos = getColumnVisiblePostion($trFirst, $td);

          // if  is the last just append it
          if(cellPos == $trFirst.children().length - 1){
            $trTarget.append($clone);
          }
          // Otherwise, insert it before its closer sibling
          else {
            tdsTarget = $trTarget.children();
            for(i = 0; i < tdsTarget.length; i++){
              cellTargetPos = getColumnVisiblePostion($trFirst, $(tdsTarget[i]));
              if(cellPos < cellTargetPos){
                $(tdsTarget[i]).before($clone);  
                break;
              }
            }                
          }          
        }
      } 
    }

    // remove tmp nodes from the previous row 
    if(rowIdx > 0){
      $tr = $(trs[rowIdx-1]);
      if(!$tr.is(':visible')){
        $tr.children(".tmp").remove();  
      }

    } 
  }
}

// this function calculates the position of a column 
// based on the visible position
function getColumnVisiblePostion($firstRow, $cell){
  var tdsFirstRow = $firstRow.children();
  for(var i = 0; i < tdsFirstRow.length; i++){
    if($(tdsFirstRow[i]).data('posx') == $cell.data('posx')){
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function add_delete_buttons() {
  var $all_rows = $("tr");
  $all_rows.each(function () {
    // TR to remove
    var $tr = $(this);
    var delete_btn = $("<button>").text("x");
    delete_btn.on("click", function () {
      $tr.hide();
      calculate_max_rowspans();
      $(window).trigger("tr_gone", $tr);
    });
    var delete_cell = $("<td>");
    delete_cell.append(delete_btn);
    $(this).append(delete_cell);
  });
}

function add_come_back_button(tr) {
  var $tr = $(tr);
  var come_back_btn = $("<button>").text("come back " + $tr.attr("color_class"));
  come_back_btn.css({"background": $(tr).css("background")});
  come_back_btn.on("click", function () {
    $tr.show();
    come_back_btn.remove();
    calculate_max_rowspans();
  });
  $("table").before(come_back_btn);
}
```

if you have any questions or comments let me know.

Comment: Your Answer looks detailed, Please specify the problem that was found if possible so that others may learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: I added more comments and changed variables names, i hope it makes it more clear

Comment: No it doesn't work for the reasons stated in my answer. Nice ideas though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the the rows to shift upward when you hide the row but you do not want the cells to shift left.

Here is what I got http://codepen.io/anon/pen/prDcK

I added two css rules:

```
#come_back_container{height: 30px;}
td[rowspan='0']{background-color: white;}
```

Here is the html I used:

```
<div id="come_back_container"></div>
<table id="dynamic_table" cellpadding=7></table>
<table id="dynamic_table2" cellpadding=7>
  <tr style="background-color: red">
    <td rowspan="5">a</td>
    <td rowspan="1">b</td>
    <td rowspan="5">c</td>
    <td rowspan="1">d</td>
    <td rowspan="2">e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: grey">
    <td rowspan="0">f</td>
    <td rowspan="1">g</td>
    <td rowspan="0">h</td>
    <td rowspan="1">i</td>
    <td rowspan="0">j</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: blue">
    <td rowspan="0">k</td>
    <td rowspan="1">l</td>
    <td rowspan="0">m</td>
    <td rowspan="1">n</td>
    <td rowspan="1">o</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: yellow">
    <td rowspan="0">p</td>
    <td rowspan="1">q</td>
    <td rowspan="0">r</td>
    <td rowspan="1">s</td>
    <td rowspan="2">t</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: green">
    <td rowspan="0">u</td>
    <td rowspan="1">v</td>
    <td rowspan="0">w</td>
    <td rowspan="1">x</td>
    <td rowspan="0">y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first rule is just to keep the top edge of the table in the same place. The second rule is to make the cells appear blank by blending in with the background, so change accordingly.

Finally here is the js:

```
$(function () {
  //firstTable()

  var myTb2 = new dynamicTable();
  myTb2.createFromElement( $("#dynamic_table2") );
  myTb2.drawTable()

  $(window).on("tr_hide", function (e,data){
    var tbl = data.ctx,
        rowIndex = data.idx;
    tbl.hideRow.call(tbl, rowIndex);
  })
  $(window).on("tr_show", function (e,data){
    var tbl = data.ctx,
        rowIndex = data.idx;
    tbl.showRow.call(tbl, rowIndex);
  })
})

function dynamicTableItem(){
  this.height = null;
  this.content = null;
}

function dynamicTableRow(){
  this.color = null;
  this.items = []
  this.show = true

  this.setNumColumns = function(numCols){
    for(var i=0;i<numCols;i++){
      var item = new dynamicTableItem(); 
      item.height = 0;
      this.items.push(item)
    }
  }

  this.addItem = function(index, height, content){
    var item = new dynamicTableItem();
    item.height = height;
    item.content = content;
    if(index>=this.items.length){ console.error("index out of range",index); }
    this.items[index] = item;
  }
}

function dynamicTable(){
  this.element = null;
  this.numCols = null;
  this.rows = []

  this.addRow = function(color){
    var row = new dynamicTableRow();
    row.color = color;
    row.setNumColumns(this.numCols)
    var length = this.rows.push( row )
    return this.rows[length-1]
  }
  this.drawTable = function(){
    this.element.empty()

    var cols = [],
        rowElements = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.numCols;i++){
      cols.push( [] )
    }

    for(var r=0; r<this.rows.length; r++){
      var row = this.rows[r]
      if(row.show){
        var $tr = $("<tr>"),
            delete_cell = $("<td>"),
            delete_btn = $("<button>").text("x")
        var data = {ctx: this, idx: r};
        delete_btn.on("click", data, function(e){
          $(window).trigger("tr_hide", e.data);
        })
        delete_cell.addClass("deleteCell");
        $tr.css( {"background": row.color} );

        delete_cell.append(delete_btn);
        $tr.append(delete_cell);
        this.element.append($tr);
        rowElements.push( $tr );

        for(var i=0; i<row.items.length; i++){
          cols[i].push( row.items[i] );
        }
      }
    }

    for(var c=0; c<cols.length; c++){
      var cellsFilled = 0;
      for(var r=0; r<cols[c].length; r++){
        var item = cols[c][r]
        var size = item.height;
        if(r>=cellsFilled){
          cellsFilled += (size>0 ? size : 1);
          var el = $("<td>").attr("rowspan",size);
          el.append(item.content);
          rowElements[r].children().last().before(el);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  this.hideRow = function(rowIndex){
    var row = this.rows[rowIndex]
    row.show = false; 

    var come_back_btn = $("<button>").text("come back");
    come_back_btn.css( {"background": row.color} );
    var data = {ctx:this, idx:rowIndex};
    come_back_btn.on("click", data, function(e){
      $(window).trigger("tr_show", e.data);
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $("#come_back_container").append(come_back_btn);

    this.drawTable();
  }

  this.showRow = function(rowIndex){
    this.rows[rowIndex].show = true;
    this.drawTable();
  }

  this.createFromElement = function(tbl){
    this.element = tbl;
    var tblBody = tbl.children().filter("tbody")
    var rows = tblBody.children().filter("tr")
    this.numCols = rows.length

    for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
      var row = this.addRow( $(rows[r]).css("background-color") );
      var items = $(rows[r]).children().filter("td");

      for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        var item = $(items[i]);
        var height = parseInt(item.attr("rowspan"));
        var contents = item.contents();
        row.addItem(i,height,contents);
      }
    }
    //console.log(this); 
  }

}

function firstTable(){
  var myTable = new dynamicTable();
  myTable.element = $("#dynamic_table");
  myTable.numCols = 5

  var red = myTable.addRow("red"); 
  red.addItem(0,5);
  red.addItem(1,1);
  red.addItem(2,5);
  red.addItem(3,1);
  red.addItem(4,2);

  var white = myTable.addRow("grey");
  //white.addItem(0,0);
  white.addItem(1,1);
  //white.addItem(2,0);
  white.addItem(3,1);
  //white.addItem(4,0);

  var blue = myTable.addRow("blue");
  //blue.addItem(0,3);  //try uncommenting this and removing red
  blue.addItem(1,1);
  //blue.addItem(2,0);
  blue.addItem(3,1);
  blue.addItem(4,1);

  var yellow = myTable.addRow("yellow");
  //yellow.addItem(0,0);
  yellow.addItem(1,1);
  //yellow.addItem(2,0);
  yellow.addItem(3,1);
  yellow.addItem(4,2);

  var green = myTable.addRow("green");
  //green.addItem(0,0);
  green.addItem(1,1);
  //green.addItem(2,0);
  green.addItem(3,1);
  //green.addItem(4,0);

  myTable.drawTable();
}
```

I tried to use clear variable and method names but if you have any quests just ask.

<strike>PS- I know there is no easy way to add content to the cells right now but you only asked for disappearing rows.</strike>

Comment: really liked your code, although I don't get why you used javascript to add rows & cells and could not parse the HTML. never mind, let me check this and if works good, it will be a good answer.

Comment: @YardenST _ I agreed with you so I redid the code so it can be used how it was the first time ( uncomment the line `firstTable()`) and now can be passed a jquery dom reference to a table element.

Comment: thanks for the addition, but its now not working good: first, why those rowspan=0 cells? second, when removing lets say red row, it shows the rowspan=0 cells, instead of copying the red cell. Your first solution was perfect! It just needs to work with an HTML table too